# Remove item from array that matches criteria mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of objects in mongoose like so:

```
myModalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    arrayData: [ {someId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, createdAt: Date }]
});
```

say `arrayData` has the following data in it:

```
arrayData = [
    {someId: 19, createdAt: Sun Dec 27 2020 11:12:58 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)},
    {someId: 27, createdAt: Sun Dec 27 2020 19:32:58 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)},
    {someId: 563, createdAt: Sun Dec 27 2020 01:22:58 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)}
]
```

How can I remove the item that `someId === 27`? (I know that 27 isn't a valid objectId, but this is just for ref.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator.

The update would look like this:

```js
Model.update({ arrayData: { someId: 27 }}, { $pull: { arrayData: { someId: 27 }}})
```